# split color hyperlink

Tags: html, css

```
<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>Hello<font color='#c0c0c0'> World</font></a>
```

the word "Hello"  is shown in the color of whatever the hyperlink is.
And "World" is shown in #c0c0c0 color. BUT "World" is underlined in the hyperlink color.
What is the best way to make the word "World" be underlined in it's same color, #c0c0c0? and keep the underline color of word "Hello" in the original hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your last words in a `<span>` and apply the desired style to it - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AcfcX/14/)

***HTML***

```
<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>
    Hello <span>World</span>
</a> ​
```

***CSS***

```css
a span { color: #c0c0c0; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Checked in IE7-9, Chrome and FF - seems to work everywhere

Comment: The first `span` is not needed. It suffices that the second word is in an element that has underline of its own; then the color of that underline is determined by the color of this element. The `</a>` tag should not be preceded by a line break; the break now causes a space to be rendered, with an underline that has the color of the link.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks, you're right. Updated the answer to use just one `span` - it makes the markup and the styles significantly cleaner. However can't reproduce the line-break issue you mentioned - tried in every browser though..